# Shaders in Fixed Function GPUs

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, gpu, direct3d

I have been reading up more about GPU architecture, and one bit sort of confuses me. Most resources define "shaders" as a piece of code that runs in various parts of the graphics pipeline to project a final render of a 3D scene. Older GPU architectures were "fixed functions"... does this mean that graphics programmers then had really no control on how filters and effects were applied to their 3D scene?

Can someone confirm with me now that we have "programmable GPUs" does this mean that the shader functions/programs are sent to the GPU?

This leads me to another thought, if graphics programmers had no control, does the term "fixed function" for the GPU mean that these shaders were implemented on hardware (through transistors/gates)? Sorry, I am a hardware newbie, so my terminology may be incorrect.

Comment: Shaders in fixed-function GPUs? The only thing that comes to mind are texture combiners. They were a weird hybrid that thought all the world's problems could be solved by performing arithmetic operations on multiple layers of textures... horrible, horrible idea that was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The legacy 'fixed-function' pipeline was not fully programmable in the modern GPU shader sense. In the earliest days, it was a software renderer with some parameters but in the late 90s it was referred to as "Hardware Transform & Light" for vertices and "Multitexturing" for pixels in Direct3D 6/7. To control the fixed-function pipeline, you set a [ton of state](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj658611.aspx) to configure it for various operations. In other words, it was *configurable* but not *programmable*.

The legacy 'fixed-function' pipeline on modern GPUs is emulated by programmable shaders, and you can see an example of how those shaders look in the Direct3D [FixedFuncEMU](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples) sample. Because it is emulated for Direct3D 9 and earlier anyhow, Direct3D 10 and later do not support the legacy fixed-function pipeline at all.

Even on modern GPUs, there are aspects of the pipeline that are 'fixed function' controlled by configurable state rather than programmable shaders, such as triangle rasterization, render target alpha blending, texture sampling, depth/stencil tests, etc. The tradeoffs here are less generality for very fast and cheap hardware implementation, allowing easy replication of these functional units.

Answer (score 3):

> Older GPU architectures were "fixed functions"... does this mean that graphics programmers then had really no control on how filters and effects were applied to their 3D scene?

No. It means that you had to be creative in the way, how you implemented effects. Some effects were absolutely impossible to implement. For other effects certain approximations were possible.

The biggest difference is, that with freely programmable GPUs (shader model 2 or later) it is to control the flow of the program down to the pixel level; think of it as being able to selectively draw with some brush tools in Photoshop or a similar program.

With fixed function GPUs what you could do was essentially equivalent to working with whole layers; you could blend them, stack several layers on top of each other, do multiple rendering passes and so on. With some creativity you could implement quite wild things. My personally proudest achievement was implementing a water ripple effect (complete with approximated refraction and reflection) using a GeForce2 class GPU (built in 1999).

> This leads me to another thought, if graphics programmers had no control, does the term "fixed function" for the GPU mean that these shaders were implemented on hardware (through transistors/gates)?

No. It means *there were no shaders at all!*

Essentially what the GPUs did where drawing plainly textured triangles to the screen, apply a fixed set of operations to the incoming geometry to transform it into place and determine local illumination values. There were a few switches you could throw to select, which specific calculations should happen, for example you could load a number of textures (up to 8 in the latest fixed function hardware) and select so called "register combiners" that selected how those textures should be "mixed" with the other stuff. For example you could have a normal map texture being dot-product mixed with a light direction vector to modulate the illumination (bump mapping); you could as well have that normal texture be used to determine the texture coordinates for a cube map look up to give the impression of reflection.

Even today on modern GPUs there are some aspects that are not fully programmable (simply because it would be very difficult to make it high performance). For example blending. It's not so much the actual blending operation that's expensive; the problem is, that it has to combine pixels in a way, that would introduce a lot of synchronization lag, if the exact operations wasn't pinned down.